# Rbac superset enable role on dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

i want to disabled acces for some user to some dashboards.

i enable DASHBOARD_RBAC feature flag in my config.py configuration file but i dont see the role filter appear in the edit propreties

```
DASHBOARD_RBAC = True
```

Comment: `DASHBOARD_RBAC` is not a separate variable, it is one of the feature flags used to customize Superset. 
In your config.py or superset_config.py (recommended) define variable `FEATURE_FLAGS = {"DASHBOARD_RBAC": True}`